# When should I use the Flask.config vs. use flask.session?

Tags: python, flask

Is there a rule for when to use `Flask.config` vs. `flask.session` to store variables?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Anything that is static, app-wide, doesn't change much, and has important information for all users, should use config. (e.g. secret keys, options to modify the app from project to project, emails, generic messages)

Session should only be used to store relevant user data as the data is modified through each page. (e.g. user login data, user preferences, user inputs from previous pages)

If you have to save something from Page 1 to Page 5 in your website for that particular user, then use session. Sessions should mainly be used based on the individual user.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, most definitely.

The config is for global, project-level variables: the location of files, keys for any APIs you might be using, your database access settings, things like that.

The session is for variables related to the current user's session on the site: their previous choices on a multi-page form, preferences, login details, etc.

You definitely don't want to get these mixed up.